# Run the script thats being edited in Liclipse, not the main from the configuration

Tags: eclipse, pydev, development-environment, run-configuration, liclipse

I've been working with Eclipse for years, but its PyDev wasn't working on my new Mac...so I swapped to LiClipse.

In Eclipse, when I have an open file that I'm editing and click run...it runs the file that's open and visible in my editor. But apparently LiClipse always tries to run the 'main' file thats set in the 'run configuration'.

Is there a way around this so I can test the module I'm actually working on and not the entire package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use F9 to run the file you're working on -- or Ctrl+F9 if it's a Python unit-test (Ctrl+F11 will always rerun the last launch by default in LiClipse -- you may change that in preferences > run/debug > launching > launch operation), although I recommend you use F9 to run your modules (or Ctrl+F9 for unit-tests), relaunch the last with Ctrl+F11, debug the last with F11.

- http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html has more details on running your modules
- http://pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html has more details on the unittest integration